# React doesn't reload component data on route param change or query change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a "home" component with links, and when you click a link the product component is loaded with the product. I also have another component which is always visible, showing links to the "recently visited products".

These links don't work when on a product page. The url updates when I click the link, and a render occurs, but the product component doesn't update with the new product.

See this example:
[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/9y877loq1w)

Here are the routes in index.js:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Route
      exact
      path="/"
      render={props => <Home products={this.state.products} />}
    />

    <Route path="/products/:product" render={props => <Product {...props} />} />

    <Route path="/" render={() => <ProductHistory />} />

    <Link to="/">to Home</Link>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>;
```

The links in ProductHistory look like this:

```
<Link to={`/products/${product.product_id}`}> {product.name}</Link>
```

So they match the `Route path="/products/:product"`.

When I am on a product page and try to follow a ProductHistory link, the URL updates and a render occurs, but the component data doesn't change. In the Codesandbox example you can uncomment the alert in Product components render function to see that it renders when you follow the link, but nothing happens.

I don't know what the problem is...Can you explain the problem and find a solution? That would be great!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Along with `componentDidMount`, You also need to implement the `componentWillReceiveProps` or use `getDerivedStateFromProps`(from v16.3.0 onwards) in `Products` page since the same component is `re-rendered`  with updated `params` and `not re-mounted` when you change the route params, this is because params are passed as props to the component and on props change, React components re-render and not re-mounted.

**EDIT:** from v16.3.0 use [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) to set/update state based on props(no need to specify it in two different lifecyle methods)

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
   if (nextProps.match.params.product !== prevState.currentProductId){
      const currentProductId = nextProps.match.params.product
      const result = productlist.products.filter(obj => {

        return obj.id === currentProductId;

      })
     return {

        product: result[0],
        currentId: currentProductId,
        result

      }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Prior v16.3.0, you would use componentWillReceiveProps

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.match.params.product !== this.props.match.params.product) {
      const currentProductId = nextProps.match.params.product
      const result = productlist.products.filter(obj => {

        return obj.id === currentProductId;

      })
      this.setState({

        product: result[0],
        currentId: currentProductId,
        result

      })
    }
  }
```

**[Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/14y47028jl)**

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is now deprecated. But how else can you do it?

Comment: @BastianVoigt : You can use integration of new lifecycle methods in react +16.3
`getDerivedStateFromProps`, `componentDidUpdate` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48139357/2101813).

Comment: I tried the `getDerivedStateFromProps` solution. But it didn't work. It seems that the `getDerivedStateFromProps` only fires once on mount.

Comment: @arvinsim, Not true, getDerivedStateFromPRops is fired on initial mount as well as on every other update. Also there was a change in this API in 16.4. I will update my answer to incorporate that change

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, thanks for the great answer.

Comment: But how can we make this work with functionnal components, now?

Answer (score 8):

As Product component is already loaded it will not reload. You have to handle new product id in the below method of component

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
if(nextProps.match.params.name.product == oldProductId){
  return;
}else {
 //fetchnewProduct and set state to reload
}
```

With latest version of react(16.3.0 onwards)

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
   if(nextProps.productID !== prevState.productID){
     return { productID: nextProps.productID};
  } 
  else {
     return null;
  }
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(prevProps.productID !== this.state.productID){
     //fetchnewProduct and set state to reload
  }
}
```

Comment: ComponentWillReceiveProps is also deprecated and considered unsafe now... is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @BastianVoigt it should be prevProps as componentDidUpdate will be called after  props has changed which will be same nextProps which we had set in getDerivedStateFromProps.

Comment: Right, but I would want to reload when the current productID (this.props.productID) is different from the one in my state, don't you think?

Comment: @BastianVoigt. Right that is what above condition does. The current productID(this.props.producID) will be having new porductID which we have had said in state variable. If we compare that then it will be always equal

Answer (score 7):

Although all the above-mentioned ways will work, I don't see a point to use `getDerivedStateFromProps`. 
Based on React docs, "if you want to re-compute some data only when a prop changes, use a memoization helper instead".

Here, instead, I would suggest simply using `componentDidUpdate` along with changing the `Component` to `PureComponenet`.

With reference to React docs, `PureComponenet`s only rerender if at least one state or prop value changes. Change is determined by doing a shallow comparison of state and prop keys.

```js
  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) => {
    if(this.props.match.params.id !== prevProps.match.params.id ) {
      // fetch the new product based and set it to the state of the component
   };
  };
```

Please note that the above only work if you change the Component to PureComponent, and obviously, you need to import it from React.

Comment: In my case it's working for regular components too.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't maintaining state in your component, you can use `componentDidUpdate` without the need for `getDerivedStateFromProps`:

```js
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { match: { params: { value } } } = this.props
    if (prevProps.match.params.value !== value){
      doSomething(this.props.match.params.value)
    }
  }
```