# How to call Redux store changes in single component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a `<Category />` component. Redux Router pases all the category/ urls inside it. The problem is with store update. I am setting `CategoryContent` store with initial values in `componentDidMount()`, but when i am navigating from category to category, it uses the same  component, so i cant chage my `CategoryContent` store in this hook. I also cant call it in my render function. So what is the right way to change my store, when i am navigating my site? Maybe there is some hoot on url change or something?

```
<DefaultPage path="/category" component={Category} />
```

so every category is set will use my `Category` component. When i go to /category I am dispatching an action to load a content by calling `loadPageContent()`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        loadPageContent: page => {
            dispatch(loadPageContent(page))
        }
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        categories: state.page.categories,
        pageContent: state.page.pageContent,
    }
}
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Category);
```

Comment: Why do you mean by `i am navigating from category to category`

Comment: When you are navigating to a category, I assume that you know this category's id, or any other unique attribute, that differentiates this category from another category, right? So why do you have a problem accessing this specific category in the store?

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139281/react-doesnt-reload-component-data-on-route-param-change/48139367#48139367

Comment: Please share some code here. This would help everyone to understand you question / problem better.

Comment: @ShobhitChittora i added some code if you need something specific just ask for )

Comment: @ ShubhamKhatri it mean that i am navigatin from category/1 to category/2 for example.