# React-Router not unmounting on location parameter change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This problem is driving me insane, I got a simple little app created by `create-react-app` and I am using `React-Router`.

### JSX:

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/pages/:pageId" component={Page} />
</Router>
```

In the Page component I have an fetch on `componentDidMount`, its working as expected first time the route is loaded.

For example I visit: `/pages/13` and then it fetches that pages data, but when I am on: `/pages/13` and then click on a Link component (imported from `React-Router`) redirecting me to: `/pages/15` - the `pageId` prop is then updated but it never re-renders.

The `Page` component never run `componentWillUnmount` before, or `componentDidMount` after.

#### Expected behavior:

1. Visit: `/pages/13` → `render()` → `componentDidMount()` → `render()`
2. Click on Link component `/pages/15` → `componentWillUnmount()` → `render()`
   → `componentDidMount()` → `render()`

---

I am using the following versions:

- react: 16.3.2
- react-dom: 16.3.2
- react-router-dom: 4.2.2

---

What am I doing wrong? I am still pretty new to React so be nice :)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [React doesn't reload component data on route param change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139281/react-doesnt-reload-component-data-on-route-param-change/48139367#48139367)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `componentDidMount` only executes when the component is completely mounted, and this only occurs one time. In this case, changing the route param doesn't change the component, I mean, you still being in the same component when you change the `pageId`, thus the `componentDidMount` is never executed again.
What could you do then?, well, I suggest you to look into `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)` method, this is executed whenever the component's props are about to be modified, which in this case, is what you are looking for, because, according to [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match):

> You’ll have access match objects in various places: 
>   Route component as this.props.match; 
>   Route render as ({ match }) => (); 
>   Route children as ({ match }) => (); 
>   withRouter as this.props.match; 
>   matchPath as the return value;

the match object (which contains the route params) is given through component's props.

So, short answer. Use `componentDidMount` for first time fetching, and then use `componentWillRecieveProps(newProps)` for all the rest fetching calls.

check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) for more info.

Note: I didn't know that `componentWillRecieveProps(newProps)` was about to be somewhat deprecated, anyways, it suggest you to use `getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)` which is basically the same

Comment: Thanks! Yeah thats why I was avoiding componentWillRecieveProps(), will look into getDerivedStateFromProps() instead

Comment: I ended up using a combination of componentDidUpdate() and getDerivedStateFromProps(). Its now working!

Comment: Nice!, I'm glad that at least I could point you to your solution :)

Answer (score 2):

When parameter is changing, your `Route` doesn't remount your component. This is an expected behaviour. You should catch the parameter changing via `componentWillReceiveProps`, otherwise if you wish to force remounting, you should use `<Route path="/your/path/with/:id" render={props => <Component {...props} key={props.params.id} />`