# react router this.props.history.push changed url but not component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm using react router v4, usually I don't have problem it, was working great even with @withRouter

`this.props.history.replace("/dashboard")`

but this time I have problem using it with redux.

https://codesandbox.io/s/pm0yvwp2jj

The route changed but why the component isn't rerendering? I should see content: clash of war if I go to `dashboard/2`, route is not switchable, only work if I refresh.

Comment: @Shubham, gerivedStateFromProps does not trigger when I put in `dashboard/index`

Comment: Since you want to fetch data, you should do so in componentDidUpdate function and not getDerivedStatefromProps. Also for getDerivedStateFromProps to work your react version needs to be >= v16.3

Comment: getDerivedStateFromProps did not trigger at all, checked the package.json, it's v16.3

Comment: please update your sandbox, I will have a look at it

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks, updated the codesandbox.. but why should I use componentDidUpdate? it doesn't have nextProps for me to compare. Strange why should I even need to compare? usually this.props.history.push work just fine.

Comment: Please read the answer to duplicate question carefully, when params update, the component is not remounted but re-rendered with updated props

Comment: getDerivedStateFromProps is a typo problem, just look the other question you asked.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri https://stackoverflow.com/a/48139367/9728810 typo for `getDerivedStateFromProps `

Comment: @Melissa92, Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer there

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri are you sure it can be solve using componentDidUpdate? See my latest codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/l53x2z4qpq, in Containers/dashboard/user/NotificationDetail, I always get the same object for `this.props.notification`.

Comment: What you are actually wanting to achieve is to fetch your notification anytime the route parameters change. This is a job for componentWillReceiveProps. If your route id parameter isn't equal between your current props and next props, dispatch fetchNotification. This should be done in an higher order component to keep things dry. I coded that quickly in your sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/6jy6y63o7r

Comment: @Eld0w why do you need hoc for this? usually container will contain many other component, so I will use componentWillReceiveProps once for each containers only

Comment: It really depends of your needs and preferences. The hoc could be used in any other place where you need your redux store loaded with notifications. (For example if you refresh the page). I prefer to put this kind of actions inside hocs as they could be needed in very various places of your app. You could also make a more generic one with the route params to check and the fetch action as arguments.

Comment: Usually I put this kind of hoc above the container class component.