# React Router - Doesn't Automatically Route on Form Submission

Tags: react-router

I'm trying to route my search field to this route:

> App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/:q' component={SearchPage} /> //trying to route here
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

> SearchField.js

```
import React from 'react'

import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class SearchField extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            query: ''
        }
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
        type === "checkbox" ? this.setState({ [name]: checked }) : this.setState({ [name]: value })
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.props.history.push(`/${this.state.query}`) //my routing attempt using history.push
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input
                        className="form-control mr-sm-2"
                        type="search"
                        name="query"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        value={this.state.query}
                        placeholder="Search"
                        aria-label="Search"
                    />
                    <button className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(SearchField)
```

So whenever I type the query onto the search field, it correctly displays it on the address bar like this:

[image]

but the front-end stays intact without changing the query (and no console errors either - completely clean). It's only when I *refresh* the page is my new query `safe`, for example, comes into play. However, I need it to *auto-refresh* whenever I fire the enter or press the `Search` button on my query without the need of *manually* refreshing the page to see my query results.

I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42716055/2924072) quite diligently and I've tried all these steps, but I'm still unsuccessful with any approach that I've read.

Comment: You could also use react router's `Link` component. Just replace the submit button with a `<Link to='/somewhere' />`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I had to use the `componentWillReceiveProps` life cycle function from React.

Code:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if ( nextProps.match.params.q !== this.props.match.params.q ) {
        fetch(`//derpibooru.org/search.json?q=${nextProps.match.params.q}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ images: data }))
    }
}
```

More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48139367/2924072).