# Manage props changes in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I m building an appointment application with react native,its my first try in RC,Using react-redux to manage the state.I need some clarification about lifecycle methods.

**Details.js**

```
class Details extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     }

   componentDidMount(){
   this.props.bookingAndSuggestions(Data)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
     if( Object.keys(nextProps.bookingSuggestionStatus).length >0) {
      if(nextProps.bookingSuggestionStatus.res.data.status=='available') {
        this.setState({isAvailable:false})
      } else {
        this.setState({isAvailable:true})
      }} }

   onBookNow=()=>{
    this.props.shops(Data);
   }
```

Here is the deal,Initially i call react-redux action prop `this.props.bookingAndSuggestions(Data)`  and i capture the response inside `componentWillReceiveProps`,and On booking `this.props.shops(Data);`  will trigger and it also updates the `componentWillrecieveprops`,the logic inside the componentwillrecieveprops updates each time when props changes.What is the proper approach to deal with such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

componentWillReceiveProps is called not only when the props change but also when the parent re-renders and hence whenever it is being called the state is being evaulated and set again.

You have two options

1. If you aren't modifying the `isAvailable` state internally, you could simply use it from props directly.

Eg:

```
const isAvailable = this.props.bookingSuggestionStatus && this.props.bookingSuggestionStatus.res.data.status=='available'
```

2. If you are modifying it, then you need to check if the props have changed which you can do in `componentWillReceiveProps`(use [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139281/react-doesnt-reload-component-data-on-route-param-change-or-query-change/48139367#48139367) from v16.3.0 onwards)

Eg:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
     if(!_.isEqual(nextProps.bookingSuggestionStatus, this.props.bookingSuggestionStatus) && Object.keys(nextProps.bookingSuggestionStatus).length >0) {
      if(nextProps.bookingSuggestionStatus.res.data.status=='available') {
        this.setState({isAvailable:false})
      } else {
        this.setState({isAvailable:true})
      }
     } 
}
```

Comment: It would also be worth noting that `componentWillReceiveProps` is [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)

Comment: @Andrew, I think I should add it explicitly in my answer if its not clear